# Mimicking another sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, sprite

So I have a sprite controlled by the player tilting their device, I need to have other sprites have the same "details/traits", like the turns as the first one, but follow it instead of being controlled by the device being tiled. Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

let Pi = CGFloat(M_PI)

let DegreesToRadians = Pi / 180
let RadiansToDegrees = 180 / Pi

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var snakeHead = SKSpriteNode()
    var snakeBody = SKSpriteNode()

    var food = SKSpriteNode()

    var Obstacle = SKSpriteNode()

    var accelerometerX: UIAccelerationValue = 0
    var accelerometerY: UIAccelerationValue = 0

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    var lastUpdateTime: CFTimeInterval = 0

    var playerAcceleration = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    var playerVelocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    let MaxPlayerAcceleration: CGFloat = 150
    let MaxPlayerSpeed: CGFloat = 100
    //Change speed of character and acceleration

    let BorderCollisionDamping: CGFloat = 0.8
    //Change speed after colliding with border

    var playerAngle: CGFloat = 0
    var previousAngle: CGFloat = 0

    let ObstacleCollisionRadius: CGFloat = 35
    let PlayerHeadCollisionRadius: CGFloat = 30
    //Radius of collision zone for the player and the obstacles

    let PlayerBodyCollisionRadius: CGFloat = 0
    //*** IGNORE ***

    let collisionSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Collision/Death.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    //File name to play on player's collision with obstacle

    let CollisionDamping: CGFloat = 0.8
    //*** TO BE REMOVED - JUST FOR EXPERIMENTAL *** Change bounce off obstacle

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        snakeHead = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "snakeHead")
        snakeHead.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
        snakeHead.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY - 50)
        self.addChild(snakeHead)

        snakeBody = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "snakeBody")
        snakeBody.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        snakeBody.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY - 100)
        self.addChild(snakeBody)

        Obstacle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Obstacle")
        Obstacle.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
        Obstacle.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        self.addChild(Obstacle)

        startMonitoringAcceleration()

    }

    deinit {

        stopMonitoringAcceleration()

    }

    func startMonitoringAcceleration() {

        if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable {
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
            NSLog("accelerometer updates on...")
        }
    }

    func stopMonitoringAcceleration() {

        if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable && motionManager.accelerometerActive {
            motionManager.stopAccelerometerUpdates()
            NSLog("accelerometer updates off...")
        }
    }

    func updatePlayerAccelerationFromMotionManager() {

        if let acceleration = motionManager.accelerometerData?.acceleration {

            let FilterFactor = 0.75

            accelerometerX = acceleration.x * FilterFactor + accelerometerX * (1 - FilterFactor)
            accelerometerY = acceleration.y * FilterFactor + accelerometerY * (1 - FilterFactor)

            playerAcceleration.dx = CGFloat(accelerometerY) * -MaxPlayerAcceleration
            playerAcceleration.dy = CGFloat(accelerometerX) * MaxPlayerAcceleration

        }
    }

        func checkShipCannonCollision() {

            let deltaX = snakeHead.position.x - Obstacle.position.x
            let deltaY = snakeHead.position.y - Obstacle.position.y

            let distance = sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY)
            if distance <= ObstacleCollisionRadius + PlayerHeadCollisionRadius {
                runAction(collisionSound)

                playerAcceleration.dx = -playerAcceleration.dx * CollisionDamping
                playerAcceleration.dy = -playerAcceleration.dy * CollisionDamping
                playerVelocity.dx = -playerVelocity.dx * CollisionDamping
                playerVelocity.dy = -playerVelocity.dy * CollisionDamping

                //This code adds the bouce when it collides, this is experimental
                let offsetDistance = ObstacleCollisionRadius + PlayerHeadCollisionRadius - distance
                let offsetX = deltaX / distance * offsetDistance
                let offsetY = deltaY / distance * offsetDistance
                snakeHead.position = CGPoint(
                    x: snakeHead.position.x + offsetX,
                    y: snakeHead.position.y + offsetY)
            }
    }

    func updatePlayer(dt: CFTimeInterval) {

        // 1
        playerVelocity.dx = playerVelocity.dx + playerAcceleration.dx * CGFloat(dt)
        playerVelocity.dy = playerVelocity.dy + playerAcceleration.dy * CGFloat(dt)

        // 2
        playerVelocity.dx = max(-MaxPlayerSpeed, min(MaxPlayerSpeed, playerVelocity.dx))
        playerVelocity.dy = max(-MaxPlayerSpeed, min(MaxPlayerSpeed, playerVelocity.dy))

        // 3
        var newX = snakeHead.position.x + playerVelocity.dx * CGFloat(dt)
        var newY = snakeHead.position.y + playerVelocity.dy * CGFloat(dt)

        var collidedWithVerticalBorder = false
        var collidedWithHorizontalBorder = false

        if newX < 0 {
            newX = 0
            collidedWithVerticalBorder = true
        } else if newX > size.width {
            newX = size.width
            collidedWithVerticalBorder = true
        }

        if newY < 0 {
            newY = 0
            collidedWithHorizontalBorder = true
        } else if newY > size.height {
            newY = size.height
            collidedWithHorizontalBorder = true
        }

        if collidedWithVerticalBorder {
            playerAcceleration.dx = -playerAcceleration.dx * BorderCollisionDamping
            playerVelocity.dx = -playerVelocity.dx * BorderCollisionDamping
            playerAcceleration.dy = playerAcceleration.dy * BorderCollisionDamping
            playerVelocity.dy = playerVelocity.dy * BorderCollisionDamping
        }

        if collidedWithHorizontalBorder {
            playerAcceleration.dx = playerAcceleration.dx * BorderCollisionDamping
            playerVelocity.dx = playerVelocity.dx * BorderCollisionDamping
            playerAcceleration.dy = -playerAcceleration.dy * BorderCollisionDamping
            playerVelocity.dy = -playerVelocity.dy * BorderCollisionDamping
        }

        snakeHead.position = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)

        let RotationThreshold: CGFloat = 10
        let RotationBlendFactor: CGFloat = 0.2

        let speed = sqrt(playerVelocity.dx * playerVelocity.dx + playerVelocity.dy * playerVelocity.dy)
        if speed > RotationThreshold {
            let angle = atan2(playerVelocity.dy, playerVelocity.dx)

            // did angle flip from +π to -π, or -π to +π?
            if angle - previousAngle > Pi {
                playerAngle += 2 * Pi
            } else if previousAngle - angle > Pi {
                playerAngle -= 2 * Pi
            }

            previousAngle = angle
            playerAngle = angle * RotationBlendFactor + playerAngle * (1 - RotationBlendFactor)
            snakeHead.zRotation = playerAngle - 90 * DegreesToRadians
        }

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */



    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

        // to compute velocities we need delta time to multiply by points per second
        // SpriteKit returns the currentTime, delta is computed as last called time - currentTime
        let deltaTime = max(1.0/30, currentTime - lastUpdateTime)
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime

        updatePlayerAccelerationFromMotionManager()
        updatePlayer(deltaTime)

        checkShipCannonCollision()

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please,  I am not grasping your english

Comment: I'm now sure on how to elaborate on it but, if you were to run that code, you would see all of the turning details and other things for the first sprite, I need another sprite to follow that spite with the same details as the first one. I'm not sure how to use my current code to make that sprite have the same details but not be controlled by the tilting.

Comment: oh so you want the second sprite to clone the first sprites movement, but with a slight delay to it so that they are not overlapping?

Comment: Yes, but have the same "details" so it is more mimicking it.

Comment: well the same details is easy,  there is a `.copy()` method available for your sprite object.  as for the following the path,  just record all of the tilts into an array as they happen, wait a tiny bit, and replay those movements

Comment: Could I have an example on going about doing this please, otherwise thanks a lot, hopefully that solves it.

Comment: I see you are trying to make a snake game,  instead of an array,  I will keep it simple for you,  let me fill an answer out